# Selenium WebDriver NullPointerException while grabbing url

Tags: java, selenium

I have found multiple answers to this issue but none that seem to help me here. When ever i run my test, I get a NullPointerException. I image it is a simple fix but I can't find it.

Here is my set up class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class TestSetUp {

private WebDriver driver;

protected StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

private void setDriver(String type, String url) {

    switch (type) {
        case Config.FIREFOX_DRIVER:
            System.out.println("Setting drivers for Firefox...");
            driver = initFireFoxDriver(url);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("invalid browser type");
    }
}

private static WebDriver initFireFoxDriver(String url) {
    System.out.println("Launching Firefox browser...");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().to(url);
    return driver;
}

@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"type","url"})
public void initializeTestBaseSetup(String type, String url) {
    try {
        setDriver(type, url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error....." + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    }
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}
}
```

This is my LoginPage class where the error is being thrown:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class LoginPage {

private WebDriver driver;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

private String getLoginTitle() {
    return driver.getTitle();
}

public boolean verifyURL() {

    return driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("login");
}

public boolean verifyLoginTitle() {
    return getLoginTitle().contains(Config.TITLE + " - Log In");
}

public boolean verifySignInError() {
    enterUsername("test");
    enterPassword("pass");
    clickLogin();
    return getErrorMessage().contains("Incorrect Username or Password");
}

public boolean verifyForgotPassword() {
    return driver.findElement(Config.FORGOT_PASS_NODE).isDisplayed();
}

public boolean verifyLicencing() {
    Config.changeSetting("multi_license", 1, driver);

    return driver.findElement(Config.LIC_KEY_NODE).isDisplayed();
}

public boolean verifyCreateAccount() {
    Config.changeSetting("user_reg", 0, driver);

    if(driver.findElement(Config.CREATE_ACCOUNT_NODE).isDisplayed()) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        Config.changeSetting("user_reg", 1, driver);
    }

    return driver.findElement(Config.CREATE_ACCOUNT_NODE).isDisplayed();
}

public HomePage signIn(String username, String password) {
    enterUsername(username);
    enterPassword(password);
    clickLogin();

    return new HomePage(driver);
}

public void enterUsername(String username) {
    WebElement identity = driver.findElement(Config.IDENTITY_NODE);
    if(identity.isDisplayed())
        identity.sendKeys(username);
}

public void enterPassword(String password) {
    WebElement pass = driver.findElement(Config.CREDENTIAL_NODE);
    if(pass.isDisplayed())
        pass.sendKeys(password);
}

public void clickLogin() {
    WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(Config.SUBMIT_NODE);
    if(loginBtn.isDisplayed())
        loginBtn.click();
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    String errorMessage = null;
    WebElement errorMsg = driver.findElement(Config.DANGER_NODE);
    if(errorMsg.isDisplayed())
        errorMessage = errorMsg.getText();
    return errorMessage;
}

}
```

And finally my test case:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LoginPageTest extends TestSetUp {

private WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    driver = getDriver();
}

@Test
public void verifyLoginInFunction() {
    System.out.println("Log In functionality being tested...");

    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);

    try {
        Assert.assertTrue("The url is incorrect", loginPage.verifyURL());
    } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }

    try {
        Assert.assertTrue("Title did not match", loginPage.verifyLoginTitle());
    } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }

    try {
        Assert.assertTrue("Error message did not match", loginPage.verifySignInError());
    } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }

    try {
        Assert.assertTrue("\'Forgot Password?\' link is missing", loginPage.verifyForgotPassword());
    } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }

    try {
        Assert.assertTrue("Create Account setting not working", loginPage.verifyCreateAccount());
    } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }

    try {
        Assert.assertTrue("Additional Licence Key setting not working", loginPage.verifyLicencing());
    } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }

    HomePage homePage = loginPage.signIn(Config.STUDENT, Config.STUDENTPASS);

    try {
        Assert.assertTrue("Login did not work", homePage.verifyURL());
    } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

I have been trying and just do not know what is causing the issue.

Comment: Do you know where this exception occurs? It's tough to try to read all of your code for the first time

Comment: @bpgeck I am sorry, yes it occurs at LoginPage.verifyURL()

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's **just** the `LoginPage.verifyURL()`? This could be caused by `loginPage` not being correctly instantiated

Comment: @bpgeck after some more tinkering, it looks like it had to with `LoginPageTest.setUp()` having the incorrect annotation. I was using `@Before` and should have been using `@BeforeClass`. Since I was using the incorrect annotation, it wasn't initializing my driver correctly causing it to just return null on everything.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out

Comment: @MichaelGibson Can you please tell me how you are using CONFIG.FIREFOX. Are you using properties file or anyother way to fetch the variable value or can you share a sample code of above. It would be helpful for me because I am trying to implement the same type of framework in my project.

Comment: @AmitHorakeri I have a java config class that holds global variables. Config.FIREFOX_DRIVER it is just an string value that represent what browser should be launched. This was early stages of the project so I did not have other options added at the time.

Comment: @MichaelGibson Thanks a lot, it helped me.!

Answer (score 0):

So, I was just dealing with this same problem and realized this question was asked about 7 years ago. I thought I would share what I have come up with as my solution.

For the instance you are trying to access you are passing a null. You assign a value to something that hasn't been initialized yet which gives you the exception you are seeing :) a null value into the driver loginPage is a no no. First initialize -> then pass value -> happy outputs.

I'm not here to give you a coding lesson as you have proven to show you know what you are doing, but happy coding!